# Measuring talk time

Tags: logging, timer

Situation: a financial advisor starts talking to a customer after starting a timer. When the conversation ends, he stops the timer and the amount of time is added to a log file with information about the customer.

Does such an application already exist?

Comment: Such an app is actually pretty easy to write. If you can't find anything online, I will do it for you. Contact me at balazsbotond at balazsbotond dot hu.

Comment: Actually, I'm a software engineer myself so I can write such a thing myself. But why re-invent the wheel if such a thing already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Task Coach](http://www.taskcoach.org/index.html)

> Task Coach is a simple open source
>   todo manager to manage personal tasks
>   and todo lists. It grew out of Frank's
>   frustration that well-known task
>   managers, such as those provided with
>   Outlook or Lotus Notes, do not provide
>   facilities for composite tasks. Often,
>   tasks and other things todo consist of
>   several activities. Task Coach is
>   designed to deal with composite tasks.

There's also an online site with a free limited account:

[myHours.com](http://www.myhours.com/)
myHours.com is a time management, timesheet, time tracking solution. It enables you to track your work time, projects you work on and tasks you perform. It is web based and can be used from any location at any time.

If not, here is a site pretending to list dozens of such [Time-tracking Freeware](http://www.softplatz.com/freeware/time-tracking/).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows and Mac, there's this rather good looking [Vertabase Timer](http://timer.vertabase.com/) with detailed log features. I seem to remember it used to be free. They are now asking $5 for it.